# Checking the first letter of a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to check the city's first letter against what a user inputs, so if they put in 'A' it will return all cities starting with the letter A.

What WHERE clause can I use to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) will do it

```
WHERE
   CityName LIKE 'A%';
```

Comment: Yes, it could be interesting to know why. Nevertheless +1 to compensate.

Answer (score 2):

[`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) is probably the best way:

```
WHERE city LIKE 'A%'
```

As the argument to `LIKE` does not start with a wildcard character, mysql can use an index for the comparison.

There's also the [`SUBSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(city, 1, 1) = 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE city LIKE 'A%'` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Option `WHERE ColName LIKE 'A%'`